# SQL correlated subquery unique construct equivalent

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

```
select T.course_id from course T 
where  1 <=    
       ( select count(R.course_id) from section R
         where R.course_id = T.course_id
         and   R.year = 2009 );
```

This query is supposed to find all courses which are offered at most once in the year 2009.
But, if we compare the result of subquery as in ***"1 <= (subquery)"***, the result of the subquery might contain duplicate tuples...so, the result of where clause might evaluate to be true even if 1<=2.

Comment: The result of the subquery will not contain duplicates, it must return a single value always and in this case, its returning an integer. If you wish to remove duplicates on the final result, try using DISTINCT or Group By t.course_id

Comment: Do you want courses having at least one (as it is in your query) or at most one (as it is in description)?

Comment: I have mentioned that the courses must not be offered more than once, i.e, no duplicate course.

Comment: Why didn't you say that your query gets you wrong results rather than telling us you are worried your subquery might contain duplicates? You could have saved us some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This query is supposed to find all courses which are offered at most once in the year 2009.

You need to swap the condition from

```
1 <= (SELECT COUNT(r.course_id) ...
```

*(which is finding the courses offered one-or-more times in 2009)*

to

```
1 >= (SELECT COUNT(r.course_id) ...
```

*(which is finding the courses offered zero-or-one times in 2009)*

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you query is equivalent to the following one

```
select T.course_id 
from course as T 
left join section as R where T.course_id = R.course_id and R.year = 2009
group by T.course_id
having count(R.course_id) <= 1
```

Use `group by` and `having` when it is possible. Is is often much better for the optimizer than subqueries.

Comment: The OP mentioned "at most once in 2009" so I think your condition should be <= 1 :)

Comment: @RigertaDemiri you are right, but in the query he selects courses having **at least** one section. So now I'm confused.

Comment: I wanted to do this using subquery because I've been asked to do this without using the unique construct.

Answer (score -1):

Your subquery only returns one single value, namely the count of sections in 2009 for the course in question. So there is no problem with the query (apart from that it's looking for courses taken at least once, where you said you wanted to look for courses taken at most once).

Comment: But, suppose a particular course_id in the outer query has been offered thrice in the year 2009 then, in that case, the subquery will give count result 3 and that will evaluate the where clause predicate to true and that course will be selected..

Comment: @Rohit Kumar: OP is counting sections per course in 2009. So it seems a section means a "course offered". This count is checked then in order to tell how often the course was offered. I see nothing wrong about this. (Apart still from the question whether the OP wants "at least once" or "at most once", as has been noted now several times and even led to MT0's separate answer.)